# Handle tmp file in form upload and pass the file to other form before uploaded

Tags: php

I need help badly , can't fix it to working like i want..!

I have two forms , one is contact form , and the other is image upload inside the contact form,the forms using AJAX for proccsesing.

[image: my form example]

I **dont** want to move_upload_file unless the all form(contact)is submited. so so far its all working, **exept** when i try to pass the file over the contact form and use`@move_upload_file` it wont move the file to the server.

I using this way to transfer the file and when i am doing var_dump its working perfect :

```
 if ($proc == "question")
{
    // Handle some normal form 'contact us'.

    // ... Some proccses code when submited via ajax ...

    $fileElementName = 'ImageBrowse';

 //This session coming from other proccses form down if isset.
  if(isset($_SESSION['imgfilename']) && !empty($_SESSION['imgfilename'])){
     //Then i handle it with list to make the rest of the proccses.
     list($uploadFilename,$_FILES['ImageBrowse']) = $_SESSION['imgfilename'];
     //unset session for security.
     unset($_SESSION['imgfilename']);
    }
   var_dump($_FILES['ImageBrowse']);
   // will print the file array perfect.

   //Trying now to move_uploaded_File 
if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageBrowse']['tmp_name'],$uploadsDirectory.$uploadFilename)){
         echo 'Uploaded!';
 }else{
        echo 'Not Uploaded';
 }
 // and here is the problem , it wont move uploaded file , even if there is array of the file..

}
else if ($proc == "sendQuestionUploadImg")
{
    // Handle img upload via ajax.

    $fileElementName = 'ImageBrowse';

    $uploadsDirectory = '../uploads/'; 

    $allowedTypes = array
        (
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/jpg',
            'image/pjpeg',
            'image/pjpeg',
            'image/png',
            'application/x-rar-compressed'
        );

    // ... Some more proccses code when submited via ajax ...

    // In the end if goes well...
    // I want to pass the file array to the other if above.

    if (isset($msg) && !empty($msg))
    {
       // I insert the file array into session for take the rest of the proccses in above form if.
     $_SESSION['imgfilename'] = array($uploadFilename,$_FILES['ImageBrowse']); 

       //If i use here , it will work.
       if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ImageBrowse']['tmp_name'],$uploadsDirectory.$uploadFilename)){
             echo 'Uploaded!';
            }else{
            echo 'Not Uploaded';
            }
       //
    }
    else
    {
        @unlink($_FILES[$fileElementName]); 
    }
```

As you see i pass the whole file array into session, and call it above in the other if proccses for more proccses, when i using `@move_upload_file` inside the `$proc == "sendQuestionUploadImg"` it will work perfect and will upload the file , but if i try to use `@move_upload_file` inside the other if it won't any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

To clear one thing out: if you have a `$_FILES` array without error, the file *is uploaded already* and stored in a temporary folder on the server `ini_get('upload_tmp_dir');`

The function `move_uploaded_file()` just moves the temporary file to a location of your choice safely.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

If this fails, your php process most likely is not able to write to the destination folder.

To debug this

- enable error reporting:

  `ini_set( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );`
- remove the error suppressing `@` in front of your `move_uploaded_file` function
- use a tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to see the Ajax response

http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-debugging-with-firebug

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay,first i using error_reporting in my php.ini, i know how to debug and use ajax , and for the move_upload_file i removed the '@' . and still i dont have any error's but the file won't come over from tmp folder to the normal folder , and also look again,i said i try use move_upload_file at sendQuestionUploadImg and its worked pefect so this mean able to write to the destination folder.